# To Change DateFormat in SQL Compact Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Is there any provision in SQL Compact Edition to set DateFormat like in SQL Server? If there is, request you to provide sample query for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Use a universal string representation in your queries, or if you use ADO.NET, use paramerized queries:

```
SELECT MyDate From MyTable WHERE MyDate = {ts ‘2009-05-11 23:00:00’}
```

http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2009/06/scripting-sql-datetime-fields-and.html

Comment: As .sdf file is like local DB, so I want to know does dateformat changes according to client machines or it will be same for all client machines? Eg: On my machine, I have dateformat as mmddyyyy and hence it is showing the same way. My question is will it change as client machine date format changes?

Comment: Erik, do you eventually know what is the setting of LCID good for? I could not find any use for it.

Comment: @VDohnal The LCID settings (set at database creation) specifies how string based data is sorted, so for example for Danish, the letters æ, ø and å come last in the alphabet

Comment: @PareshJadhav A sdf file is not like localdb at all, and how dates are displayed will depend on the tool you use to display it (and the tool may decide to dfiplay date based on current locale)

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Compact edition does not support the command `SET DATEFORMAT` or its equivalent.

However you may try to specify LCID when creating the database `.sdf` file. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171966%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

To create SQL database with e.g. Czech LCID you can use:

```
  using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
  ...
  string connStr = @"Data Source='c:\Test.sdf'; LCID=1029; Case Sensitive = FALSE";
  SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connStr);
  engine.CreateDatabase();
  engine.Dispose();
```

However when I try

```
  SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydate='10.2.2014'
```

It returns 0 recrds but:

```
  SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydate='20140210'
```

returns 1 record.

Also

```
  INSERT INTO mytable (mydate) VALUES ('30.7.2014')
```

returns format error.

So it seems you will have to use standard format like '20140210', do `CONVERT` or `CAST` or deal with it in some other way in your code.

Comment: As .sdf file is like local DB, so I want to know does dateformat changes according to client machines or it will be same for all client machines? Eg: On my machine, I have dateformat as mmddyyyy and hence it is showing the same way. My question is will it change as client machine date format changes?

Comment: if you use `'20140210'` or ErikEJ answer, it is universal format. So using it in WHERE or INSERT is OK.